# Passing data from a controller to a view (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I am having a small issue where I cannot pass the data to the view.

In the controller I have

```
ViewBag.InvalidParts = Invalid;
```

In the view I have

```
<h2>@Html.DisplayText("InvalidParts")</h2>
```

I get this error on my web page:

System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

When I step through my code I do see that my view bag has 20 records stored in it, my problems is that I cannot view them. Am I making a wrong call? Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Its not a error. The default ToString() implementation of List will print the type of the list, not the contents itself. That's why you receive System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String].

Comment: You're trying to print a list object and not the values contained within the list, you need something like for loop to iterate over the list and display the contents inside the list

Comment: Thank you for the response. I added a foreach loop but now I get an error that says Object reference not set to the instance of the object. Even though I know my Viewbag has the data. I must not be passing the contents of the list correctly.

Comment: can you post your foreach code?

Comment: '@foreach (var Invalid in ViewBag.InvalidParts)
             {
                 <h2>@Html.DisplayText("InvalidParts")</h2>
             }'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your foreach you need to use the variable that you have defined.  In this situation I don't think you need the helper.  Try changing your code to

```
@foreach(var invalid in ViewBag.InvalidParts){
    <text>
        <h2>@invalid</h2> 
    </text>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am able to now see the data on the screen. However, I still get the Object reference not set to the instance of the object when the page first loads. When the page firs loads that view bag is null. Should I check for null on the view or the model?

Comment: Every time I have gotten that error it was from trying to populate a list on the controller without first initializing it.  without seeing more of your code I can't tell you where that might be.  just look for where you are populating lists and make sure it is initialized

Comment: Perfect. You have been great. Got it 100% thanks for the help. By the way for the null issue I enclosed my foreach code in @if (ViewBag.InvalidParts != null)